# Cannot connect ClearCore and Kinco HMI

Tags: c, arduino, serial-port, ip, ethernet

I have been working on this for almost 3 weeks now and cannot find a solution. I am trying to output information from my Teknic ClearCore to a Kinco HMI (GL070E) by ANY means. I have tried both Serial communication (RS232) and Ethernet (still lost on this but I attempted the modbus technique). below are some links to things I have tried for this. the best one seems to be the Tools40 modbus library, but clearcore doesn't support that i guess. please help.

https://github.com/IndustrialShields/arduino-Tools40

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W-7s52zUVng

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KRno6stglPk&list=PL10EF6AF38416A66F&index=4

below is my code and it's a mess because I'm panicking:

```
#include "ClearCore.h"

// Defines the analog input to control commanded velocity
#define Estop ConnectorDI8 //Estop
#define counter ConnectorIO2 //induction3


// Select the baud rate to match the target device.
#define baudRate 9600




int count = 0;
int d = 1;
int x = 0;
int r = 0;

void setup() {
    // Put your setup code here, it will only run once:


    // Sets up serial communication and waits up to 5 seconds for a port to open.
    // Serial communication is not required for this example to run.
    
    Serial.begin(baudRate);
    uint32_t timeout = 5000;
    uint32_t startTime = millis();
    while (!Serial && millis() - startTime < timeout) 
      {
          continue;
      }

    
    
    //Configure Serial communication to HMI.
      // Configure COM-0 for RS-232 mode.
      ConnectorCOM0.Mode(Connector::RS232);
      // Set the data baud rate.
      ConnectorCOM0.Speed(9600);
      // (Optional) Set the data frame parity.
      ConnectorCOM0.Parity(SerialBase::PARITY_E);
      // (Optional) Set each data frame to use 2 stop bits.
      ConnectorCOM0.StopBits(2);
      // (Optional) Enable flow control.
      //ConnectorCOM0.FlowControl(true);
      // Open the serial port to enable data transmission.
      ConnectorCOM0.PortOpen();

}

void loop() {
/****Reset circuit***************************************************************************************************/
if (ConnectorIO1.State()==HIGH && r == 1)
  {
    digitalWrite(IO0, true);
    delay(300);
    r = 0;
    
  }

/****Estop circuit***************************************************************************************************/
while (ConnectorDI8.State()==LOW)
  {
    r = 1;
    digitalWrite(IO0, false);
  }


if (r==0)
  {
      Serial0.write(count);
      Serial.println(count);

  /****COUNTER*****************************************************************************************/
      
      if (ConnectorIO2.State() == HIGH)
        {
          count++;
        }

  }
}
```

Comment: I see a big pile of code, most of which has nothing to do with communications between two devices, and nothing describing any problem that you are having ("doesn't work" is not a useful description).  What have you done to verify that `setup` worked correctly, for example?

Comment: I have no way to prove that setup works correctly because my initial intent was to simply configure the COM port to send data to the HMI but i have no way of Addressing it (addresses required to control bit states on the HMI) so I attempted to use the tools40 modbus technique to communicate over ethernet instead, however clearcore doesn't seem to support the tools40 library that i imported even though typical arduino would i just get compile errors everytime i try to include the modbus libraries. i either need to know how to send data to specific addresses over serial or make the modbus work

Comment: Pick one technique, remove all the extraneous code, and make a [mre].  You can't debug the whole world at once.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Code has been trimmed. I didn't put "Serial0.write" under the e-stop and reset snippets because the data would interfere, so right now i'm just looking to output the count data, but all that data will eventually have to be output simultaneously.